# Docker- what real value does it bring for our team?

Tags: testing, docker, continuous-integration

I am very very new to Docker. Our team has had a very nice deployment line up where We have different CI engines for different projects including Jenkis and TeamCity.

Developers usually check-in and CI takes over, deploys and its perfectly ready for test team to test. I always thought this to be a perfect model. Of course, some parts and our implementation have their flaws but it worked very well for what we wanted.

Now, our Dev-Ops is introducing Docker where test teams get a Docker Image from Docker Registry Everytime we run a build from teamcity. While it sounds really really fancy I am still failing to understand the benefit of it.

After my research, my conclusion was that Dockers can be a good light weight replacements for VM. BUT that is ONLY IF you are using any VMs? We are not using any VMS? I just do not understand what is the real value here? Also, while searching I found a relatively good link on Docker:

https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/what-is-docker-and-when-to-use-it/

Where they discuss when you should use Docker and one of the point says that:

Use Docker whenever your app needs to go through multiple phases of development (dev/test/qa/prod, try Drone or Shippable, both do Docker CI/CD)

Ok. Howeve rthey do not further elaborate on why is docker useful when my app has to go through multiple phases?

And how it is exptremely helpful over regular Dev/Test set up when the existing set up is already working smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are right about comparing it to VMs in that it is similar to a VM. However, docker is incredibly lightweight. This property is the one that surprised me most in the beginning. As opposed to virtual machines, containers share resources much more efficiently. Virtual machines are isolated. Containers can run simultaneously on a host machine with very little overhead. You can configure containers to be able to talk to each other (via volume or port bindings).

Furthermore, in my team, docker brings the following benefits:

- our application consists of one big application and several other few microservices. But we want to release all as one package with inter-dependencies among the applications, which eliminates problems with figuring out which version of application and microservices should be deployed together (compatiblity) etc. That is, the image contains all you need and you can bring all applications or one-by-one up/down using docker-compose. You do not need to deploy, you simply pull the image and fire a container/s. If you wish to stop one of the microservices, it can be done without affecting the others.
- developers in the team, can run the very same image on local machine, for example to troubleshoot a problem occurred in the production; which means troubleshooting can be done in the same environment as in the production. This brings environment standardization and no more "but it works on machine" talk.
- another benefit it brings to us is the following: we build a docker image, run our tests against it, and push it to the registry once all these phases succeed, which translates into a great portability.
- Ability to version control the containers. You can easily inspect containers between the current version and the previous versions. If you wish to rollback - that is done  smoothly.
- Isolating and securing applications. All containers are isolated and you can easily control what goes in and out.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a year before I got used to the idea, but now it seems simple enough.

I think part of that comes from the fact that people keep calling Docker a "virtual machine", which is not accurate. That's really just a nickname for what's happening behind the scenes. In a lot of ways, Docker will NOT replace a complete virtualization solution, such as VMWare. It does, however, bring forth a new way of thinking about infrastructure. One that many people have a difficult time wrapping their heads around.

You can start asking yourself: What makes a Linux distribution unique?

Aside from the kernel, everything else is just a "standard way" of organizing binaries, libraries, runtime and configuration files. You need your binaries in /bin, your libs in /lib, your configuration in /etc. User installations get placed under /usr...

Most distributions will keep the main structure from the Unix legacy and add its own quirks. Each one will have its own way to manage and distribute packages. Each will maintain their own versions of libraries, drivers, etc.

The key ingrident is the kernel. That's something they all have in common. Nowadays, recent builds of the Linux kernel are compatible with pretty much all major distributions available. So, aside from /boot, most of everything else is just a matter of having the right files in the right place with the right permissions.

Now, imagine you take all that distribution bundle (except the kernel) and place it all in another directory of your running OS. Taking advantage of the same kernel you are already running, you isolate a new process so that it "thinks" that / is now that directory. Bingo! This process now "thinks" it's running all by itself on another operating system.

Docker builds on top of [Linux Containers](https://linuxcontainers.org/), which allows us to do excatly that, but in a more friendly and easier way. Don't think of it as a virtual machine. Think of it as process isolation. The running kernel will share the machine's resources with this process, while keeping it isolated from the rest of the system. It's like [jails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) on steroids.

That was a broad simplification. But, given the concept, think about the implications of this idea.

You can have on the same host, multiple processes with completely different environments that might otherwise conflict with each other. One may be a legacy binary that needs old libraries in place (legacy systems that never die). Another may be the most recent build of a bleeding edge technology. Sharing the same kernel is a efficient, and valuable resource management.

The most value I found comes from managing the infrastructure. Once you install Docker on the hosts, configure a swarm, and define a way of deploying containers, you mostly forget about the hosts. Adding users, installing packages, customizing, editing configuration files... All that becomes a development task on your desktop. There's an incentive to script more, to automate more. To keep your hands away from the physical or virtual machines, unless absolutely necessary.

Gone are the days when someone changed some obscure setting on the server to work around some weird application behavior, forgot to tell anyone about it and took a vacation. Changes to the environment can be commited to version control, tracked and improved by everyone on the team. If your datacenter goes through a disaster, recreating the whole environment is a matter of rebuilding images and redeploying containers. Your infrastructure becomes consistent and reproducible, while keeping the doors open to a wide variety of operating systems and customized configurations for each application.

Developers can take advantage of Docker with the ability of recreating dev/staging/production environments on their desktops. No need to polute a dev machine with application servers and database installations, or even the toll of Virtual Box to emulate all that.

Testing can be automated with a higher level of isolation. The Selenium team already has [official Docker images](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium). Creating an entire test hub should be a walk in the park with those puppies.

Building custom software, such as compiling Nginx with third party modules, can also be done inside containers from specialized images. No need to keep an entire server dedicated to it, or even polute your desktop with all the dependencies and build packages.

Overall, we've been having a great experience with Docker. We've migrated our staging environment to this new platform, and plan to migrate other parts of the infrastructure as well, eventually into production. So far, so good.

I hope you can convince enough people to take a better look at it. I'll admit, it took me sometime to get used to the idea. But once you get it, it's actually worth it.